# Opening Chrome causes Ubuntu to freeze

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, freeze

Ubuntu v14.04
Simply opening the Chrome browser causes Ubuntu to freeze completely. No key strokes are effective and the mouse pointer is frozen in place or disappears. After a hard reboot, I opened other programs including Firefox in order to reassure myself that it was most likely Chrome causing the issue.

I saw posts suggesting various actions, such as clearing your history, that require getting into the Chrome menu but it freezes before I have the chance to try. I do have various extensions enabled so I tried opening Chrome from the command line with the flag --disable-plugins and that bought me a few seconds but then everything froze anyway.

Comment: try doing     google-chrome --disable-gpu

Comment: Thanks! That worked, so should I just do that from now on or is it indicative of a different problem that I can fix?

Comment: You should do it from now as i don't see any solution. But you can try reinstalling chrome or even using chromium web browser.

Comment: Reinstalling was the first thing I did, but i keep seeing chromium referenced so though I'm not familiar, I'll look into that. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Run Chrome from a terminal with the flag --disable-gpu

```
    google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

Then select:

Options - Settings - Show Advanced Settings

Under the **System** heading, uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It was GPU related but instead of disabling it, I went to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and switched from the (open source) drivers to the first choice which was the (proprietary, tested) one. Everything working flawlessly now.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing chromium its a open source version of chrome that works just as well. It just has different icons. You can download chrome apps and the bookmarks link.